# How do i generate HTML in React functional component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to generate HTML inside of the react component, but i don't know how to do it correctly. Here is my code:

```
import React from 'react'

const Pagination = (props) => {
  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= props.pages; i++) {
    items.push(`<li class="page-item" value=${i} onClick={props.handleClick}><a class="page-link" href="/#">${i}</a></li>`)
  }
  return (
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example" className='mb-5' style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }} >
      <ul class="pagination ">
        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="/#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        {items}

        <li class="page-item">
          <a class="page-link" href="/#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```

In this case it just  pushes a string value to the array. Is there any way to fix it ?

Comment: Remove the `\`` and `$` characters: `items.push(<li value={i} ... />)`

Comment: @Chris G yes it fixed it thanks a lot

Comment: Keep in mind you are working with JSX not html within the function. Will get rendered as html but that is different and is after the function gets compiled

Comment: @Chris G if you could post your answer, i'd accept it since you answered  first. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the backticks ` and $, otherwise this will not be interpreted as JSX.

Also, when working with JSX you use attribute `className` instead of `class`, to avoid confusion with the JS reserved word class.

```
import React from 'react'

const Pagination = (props) => {
  let items = []
  for (let i = 0; i <= props.pages; i++) {
    items.push(<li className="page-item" value={i} onClick={props.handleClick}><a className="page-link" href="/#">{i}</a></li>);
  }
  return (
    <nav aria-label="Page navigation example" className='mb-5' style={{ overflowX: 'scroll' }} >
      <ul className="pagination ">
        <li className="page-item">
          <a className="page-link" href="/#" aria-label="Previous">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&laquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>

        {items}

        <li className="page-item">
          <a className="page-link" href="/#" aria-label="Next">
            <span aria-hidden="true">&raquo;</span>
          </a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </nav>
  )
}

export default Pagination
```